# Is there a way to implement PWA with video chat for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to implement PWA for mobile devices that would include messaging as well as video conference call options. Is this possible with the limitations of PWA on both iOS and Android?

I've looked for real solutions like that and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can implement it as a website, you can also create a PWA from that website. You could cache the application shell and have the video call functionality within that shell.

There won't be a need for offline usage, but your app should still launch and give feedback on the network state.

I personally do not have experience with creating a video call application, but I found [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-video-chat-service-with-javascript-webrtc-and-okta) for you. You should probably start with implementing this as a web app and then convert to a PWA by building a manifest and add a service worker.